# Visual Studio 2010 WinForm designer gives error "GUID should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes"

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

Oddest thing ever. I've gone into Visual Studio 2010 this morning and when I try to edit an existing WinForm or add a new Winform, I get the error "GUID should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes" come up.

To the best of my knowledge there have been no changes.

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the designer in another instance of Visual Studio for debugging:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996457.aspx

To me this looks like a custom exception that someone has added, can't say I've seen that before and the message doesn't sound very Microsoft-y.